# I am trying to have a second slider on the same page but its not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a second slider on the same page but its not working.
The first one works fine but the second one is not working. I think there is something wrong with the parent element method but cant wrap my head around it.

```js
var ids = ["view_0", "view_1", "view_2", "view_3"]
let current_id = 0;

function next(productnr) {
  if (document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).parentElement.id == productnr) {
    let last_array_position = ids.length;
    document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).classList.remove("show");
    current_id++;
    if (current_id >= last_array_position) {
      current_id = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById(ids[current_id]).classList.add("show");
  }
}
```

```css
#1 img {
  display: none;
}

#1 img.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<article id=1>
    <img class="show" id="view_0"></img>
    <img id="view_1"></img>
    <img id="view_2"></img>
    <img id="view_3"></img>
    <button><</button>
    <button onclick="next(1)">></button>
    <article id=2>
      <img class="show" id="view_0"></img>
      <img id="view_1"></img>
      <img id="view_2"></img>
      <img id="view_3"></img>
      <button><</button>
      <button onclick="next(2)">></button>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't show any slider though. You say the first one works, but here, both seem broken. It may be related to two `<article>` tags open but not closed.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is that you are making use of the same `id` for both sliders in `HTML`. This will always update the former but never change the latter slide by your `JavaScript` function. Also, your code has a few issues like the tags aren't closed properly, no `src` attributes. Looks like you need multiple arrays for storing ids of multiple sliders, and multiple functions to handle previous and next buttons.

Here's a common function to handle all buttons of multiple sliders on a single page without any arrays:

```js
function next(productId, next) {
  var tags = document.getElementById(productId).getElementsByTagName("img");
  var index;
  for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    if (tags[i].className == "show") {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  tags[index].classList.remove("show")
  index = next ? (index + 1) : (index - 1);
  index = index == tags.length ? 0 : index == -1 ? tags.length - 1 : index;
  tags[index].classList.add("show")
}
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

img.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="product1">
  <img class="show" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" />
  <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/61DiwECVps74bWazF88Cy9/2cc9411d050b8ca50530cf97b3e51c96/Image_Cover.jpg?fit=fill&w=480&h=270" />
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dmlld3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" />
  <img src="https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg" />
  <button onclick="next('product1', 0)">Prev</button>
  <button onclick="next('product1', 1)">Next</button>
</div>

<div id="product2">
  <img class="show" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg" />
  <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/61DiwECVps74bWazF88Cy9/2cc9411d050b8ca50530cf97b3e51c96/Image_Cover.jpg?fit=fill&w=480&h=270" />
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dmlld3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" />
  <img src="https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg" />
  <button onclick="next('product2', 0)">Prev</button>
  <button onclick="next('product2', 1)">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document,
In your code you are using the same ID for multiple elements,

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do, I would suggest to use `querySelector` to select the `elements` as this will enable us to select exactly the component with the given `id` under the given `slider` since **there are multiple elements with same id (*In such repetitive case, the suggested way is using `class` instead of `id`*)**.

- I am taking a `counter_id` as `counter of image` for each slider having the id as the key of the slider.
- Here, I updated the `slider id` as `a1` and `a2` for better understanding.
- `#${productnr}>.show#${ids[current_id[productnr]]}` => select the element with `class .show` and `id #view_0` *(or so on as per counter_id of the slider)* under the the element with `id a1` *(or a2)* i.e. slider element.
- We perform add and remove class operation on the element.

```js
var ids = ["view_0", "view_1", "view_2", "view_3"]
let current_id = {
  a1: 0,
  a2: 0
}; //image counter for each slider having the id as the key of slider

function next(productnr) {
  let last_array_position = ids.length;
  let pic = document.querySelector(`#${productnr}>.show#${ids[current_id[productnr]]}`);
  pic.classList.remove("show");
  current_id[productnr]++;
  if (current_id[productnr] >= last_array_position) {
    current_id[productnr] = 0;
  }
  document.querySelector(`#${productnr}>#${ids[current_id[productnr]]}`).classList.add("show");
}

function prev(productnr) {
  let last_array_position = ids.length;
  let pic = document.querySelector(`#${productnr}>.show#${ids[current_id[productnr]]}`);
  pic.classList.remove("show");
  current_id[productnr]--;
  if (current_id[productnr] < 0) {
    current_id[productnr] = last_array_position - 1;
  }
  document.querySelector(`#${productnr}>#${ids[current_id[productnr]]}`).classList.add("show");
}
```

```css
#a1 img {
  display: none;
}

#a1 img.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<article id="a1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200" class="show" id="view_0"></img>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200" id="view_1"></img>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/200" id="view_2"></img>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/200" id="view_3"></img>
  <button onclick="prev(`a1`)"><</button>
  <button onclick="next(`a1`)">></button>
  <article id="a2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/50/200" class="show" id="view_0"></img>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/60/200" id="view_1"></img>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/70/200" id="view_2"></img>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/80/200" id="view_3"></img>
    <button onclick="prev(`a2`)"><</button>
    <button onclick="next(`a2`)">></button>
  </article>
</article>
```